# Angular Material Tab Active issue

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm beginner for the Angular and Angular Material, I used mat-tab

The active mat-tab is always the first tab, anyone know how to activate the 2nd tab
when the using Angular material?

**code**

```
<mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the `selectedIndex` property

```
<mat-tab-group class="m-t-30" [selectedIndex]="1">
```

Comment: @core114 sure. make sure to check as answer if this helped.

Answer (score 4):

use the selectedIndex="yourvalue". you can use this property like this

```
<mat-tab-group class="m-t-30" [selectedIndex]="yourvalue">
```

or you can always do it dynamically by adding a loop or an iteration for each click event in your component and increment the value of the tabs, incase you have a lot of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

### Mat Tab active :-

use the mat-tab-label-active

---

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
      background-color : red;
      font-size : 15px
    }
```